# Is it possible to access a WebAssembly instance's exported memory from one of the host functions it imports in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly

I've been handwriting some WebAssembly modules to learn how they work. Right now I'm trying to understand how imports and exports work, and how to perform IO.

The module is as follows:

```
(module
  (import "env" "print_string" (func $print_string (param i32)))

  (func $main (result i32)
    i32.const 1024
    call $print_string

    i32.const 0
  )

  (memory $memory 2)
  (data (i32.const 1024) "example\00")

  (export "memory" (memory $memory))
  (export "main" (func $main))
)
```

So far, I've been using [`wasmtime`](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime) (which is a WebAssembly API written in Rust) to run this module. With `wasmtime`, I can instantiate a [`Linker`](https://docs.rs/wasmtime/0.29.0/wasmtime/struct.Linker.html) which will take care of wrapping the `print_string` function coming from the host that I pass to the module. The wrapped `print_string` function has access to an extra [`Caller`](https://docs.rs/wasmtime/0.29.0/wasmtime/struct.Caller.html) argument which allows me to inspect the instantiated module exports, grab the memory and read the null-terminated string off of it. This is what allows me to both export the memory and still have access to the instantiated module's memory in the imported functions.

Is this possible in the WebAssembly's JavaScript API? I am looking at the API available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API) but nothing seems to point to the fact that this is possible.

The only solution that I see working in the JavaScript API is: instead of exporting the memory from the module, the module also imports the memory from the host. This way the imported functions can also have access to the memory object. Ideally I would like for the module to export its own memory though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Javascript you can do something like

```
new Uint8Array(wasmInstance.exports.memory.buffer)
```

to access the whole memory you exported as Byte Array.
For example i use this to export the first bytes of the memory into an canvas

```
  var wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
  var wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule,{
    gfx: {
      flip: function() {
        imageData.data.set(new Uint8Array(wasmInstance.exports.mem.buffer,0,canvasWidth*canvasHeight*4));
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      }
    }
  });
  wasmInstance.exports.init();
```

you can see the whole demo here:
[http://worlddominationcommittee.org/~lee/filez/wasm/test5.html](http://worlddominationcommittee.org/%7Elee/filez/wasm/test5.html)

Comment: Yes, that much I am aware. My question is: Is it possible to access that exported memory in the functions that the instance imports? Because it seems to me that the exported memory would only become available *after* the module is instantiated with the functions that also need to access the instance's exported memory.

Comment: Yes you can. I edited some sample code in to clarify it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that JavaScript allowed this kind of self-reference. I am going to try this out later and then report back.